# How to loop A-Frame animation forever using duration attribute

Tags: animation, rotation, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I have a earth object that I would like to rotate using animation in A-frame.
I just want the object to rotate forever and I don't know how to do it. 
Below is my code thanks!

```
    <a-sphere rotation="45 0 0" position="-44.277 50 -80.933" radius="30" src="images/earth.png" roughness="0.6">

        <a-animation attribute="rotation"
                     easing="linear"
                     dur="10000"
                     to="0 360 0"
                     repeat="indefinite">

        </a-animation>
    </a-sphere>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is correct. It will take 10,000 ms (10 seconds) to complete 1 rotation, and it will repeat indefinitely ("forever"). I just tested the code and it works. If the `earth.png` texture isn't appearing, it may be difficult to see the sphere rotation. If you use the same code on an `<a-box>`, for example, it's much more obvious.

That said, since you have the `rotation` for the `<a-sphere>` set to `45` along the `x` axis and have the `<a-animation>` set to rotate to `360` over the `y` axis, it will not rotate in a linear fashion.

This can be remedied by adding a container `<a-entity>` element and setting the default `position` and `rotation` on that entity, removing it from the `<a-sphere>`, which will now be positioned relative to its container.

Here is demo: https://codepen.io/dansinni/pen/MVgqxd

Note that I had to use a different texture for the Earth.